# Envers not working with unidirectional many-to-many

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-envers

I have unidirectional many-to-many between Users and Roles. Users have many roles.
When I create a user and assign roles and when i change roles set, envers thinks that roles list is empty.
What am I missing?

Tables in db:

- AdminRole
- AdminRole_AUD
- AdminUser
- AdminUser_AUD
- AdminUserRole
- AdminUserRole_AUD

Classes:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="AdminUser")
@Audited
public class AdminUser {

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
@JoinTable(name="AdminUserRole", 
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="admin_user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="admin_role_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
@AuditJoinTable(name = "AdminUserRole_AUD", 
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="admin_role_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
private List<AdminRole> adminRoles;

    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AdminRole")
@Audited
public class AdminRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;    
}
```

Comment: Are you properly commiting the transaction? Do other audit entries appear? Which version of Hibernate?

Comment: @adamw, transaction is committed properly, entity AdminUser has other fields and they are all reflected correctly, only Roles list is empty. Version of hibernate is 4.3.0.Final

Comment: @adamw, when I create a new AdminUser, 2 new records get added to AUD tables in database - one in table AdminUser_AUD, one in AdminUserRole_AUD. There's no record created in AdminRole_AUD.

Comment: Hmm, well, "should work" :). You are using the same version of Envers as of Hibernate?

Comment: @adamw, yes, both Envers and Hibernate are 4.3.0.Final.
Thanks for looking into this. Still haven't solved.